# How to convert epoch timestamp to datetime with timezone in moment js?

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, momentjs

How to convert epoch timestamp `1527140580` to `Thu May 24 2018 11:13:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` in moment js ?

```
moment.unix(1527140580).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
```

gives me `24/05/2018 11:13`

Comment: you can use `new Date(timestamp)` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it

```js
console.log(moment.unix(1527140580).toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If the timezone at the end is important, you can read the [timezone docs here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/) to enable it in that string.

```js
var abbrs = {
    IST : 'Indian Standard Time'
};

moment.fn.zoneName = function () {
    var abbr = this.zoneAbbr();
    return abbrs[abbr] || abbr;
};

console.log(moment.tz(moment.unix(1527140580),"Asia/Calcutta").format('ddd MMMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ (zz)'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.16/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = moment(1527140580);
result.toString() // "Sun Jan 18 1970 21:42:20 GMT+0530"
```

Comment: `1527140580` is not supposed to be 1970

Comment: the actual date is `24/05/2018 11:13`

Comment: @Arbaaz its giving `Sun Jan 18 1970 21:42:20 GMT+0530 (IST)` on date

Comment: Exactly. It should be `Thu May 24 2018 11:13:00 GMT+0530 (Indian Standard Time)` and not `Sun Jan 18 1970 21:42:20 GMT+0530 (IST)`